Running a Java Based Game inside Wordpress Post or Page
I am using a puzzle generator app to create interactive word search and crossword puzzles. I am getting the following files:
Files generated by the app
How can I use those files to run the game inside a Wordpress post?
Thank you!
gd
I already tried uploading the page directly as a static page, and it did not work. However, I am open to hearing all suggestions. I am more of a designer than a programmer.

Well... you don't. Java applets, the old way of embedding Java applications in HTML documents, have been deprecated for a decade now. You can use Web Start to launch Java code downloaded from your link, but if you have some notion of running the app in the browser, you'd have to rewrite it in JavaScript.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
